# retrieving direct messages twitter api [empty array]

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to get the messages from the inbox.

Iam using the API 1.1, the tokens ar created, using GET /1.1/direct_messages/events/list.json and the code doesn"t display any errors.

Anyhow, the i can not get the messages/conversations from any chat.
The Doc in twiter is not helping me.

The result is an empty array.

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/list.json";
$getfield = "?count=50";        
$requestMethod = "GET";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string =  json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                     ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                     ->performRequest(), $assoc = TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($string);
echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [events] => Array
        ()
    [next_cursor] => MTEyNTg1ODY2OTAzMDI1MjU0OA
)
```